# Registration process with mail confirmation in Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

I have question about registration process in selenium. Which way is best to do it if we must click activation link in received email? Which method is used by commercial QA teams?
I am thinking about this problem and I want to use sites like '10 minutes mail', is that a good way?
There's any other options? I can't use same mail multiple times.
Creating new 'true' mail every time will be difficult and will take too much time, there will be captcha problems etc

Comment: Where does the activation link saved by your application? If it is saved in a database, it might be easier to read the database to get the link rather than actually using a *real* email ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a mailbox as registration mail, which supply API to read mail content in inbox, rather than only can from UI. Therefore you can easier to get the activation link and send http request to simulate click activation link.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular gmail account, there is a trick with '+' character and You can re-use multiple times, and mail is getting received on same account.

So You can use like this: open gmail with desired address, eg. address **testmail@gmail.com**, so You can reuse it in following iterations:

- testmail+1@gmail.com
- testmail+2@gmail.com
- ...
- testmail+test1@gmail.com
- testmail+test2@gmail.com

and so You can have...lot of accounts. I've used this method and its quite sufficient.